# Counting all .class files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, count

I want to count all `.class` file in my project directory. I am working on ubuntu. I can list all the class file like this -

```
find . -type f -name '*.class'
```

It lists a lot of `.class` files. But I want to know the count of these `.class` files. Is there any way to do this in linux.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `wc -l`.

[`wc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wc) stands for "word count", and its `-l` flag makes it count lines.

Since your command outputs a line per file<sup>[1](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wc)</sup>, counting lines means counting files.

```
find . -type f -name '*.class' | wc -l
```

<sup>[1](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wc)</sup> please note @chepner's comment

Comment: For Java class files (where the name must match the name of the class), this is safe. In general, a file name *could* contain a newline, which would artificially inflate the count. Instead of outputting the filename itself, output a fixed string free of newlines (`find . -type f -name '*.class' -exec echo 1`, or more efficiently where supported `find ... -printf "\1n"`).

Comment: @chepner there are slightly better ways to arrange `printf`: if GNU `find` is used, `find ... -printf 'x'` and then count the number of chars; with a `find` that doesn't support `printf`, use the system `printf`: `find ... -exec printf '%.sx' {} +` and same thing, count the number of chars. To count the number of chars, you can: `xs=$(find ... -printf x); echo "${#xs}"`.